Edit DropDownMenuEntry in Flutter
Is it possible to edit  the square from the DropDownMenuEntry in Flutter? My actual source code::
Container(
  width: screenWidth / 10,
  height: screenHeight / 22,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
    items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'value1',
        child: Text('Label 1'),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'value2',
        child: Text('Label 2'),
      ),
      // Add more items here as needed
    ],
    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
      setState(() {
        //selectedValue = newValue;
      });
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
    iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
    iconSize: 24,
  ),
);

I am doing a research but I didn't find anything.

Yes, add borderRadius as a property of the DropdownButtonFormField. It is different from the borderRadius defined in the decoration property.
decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),

